# Making pasta: is oil justified?

Tags: pasta, oil, boiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does oil in the boiling water prevent the spaghetti from sticking together?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3994/does-oil-in-the-boiling-water-prevent-the-spaghetti-from-sticking-together)

Since time immortal I have added a couple tablespoons of oil to the water when cooking pasta. I have recently heard statements to the effect that there is no justification for the practice. Is that true? If not, what is a legitimate reason for adding oil to the water?